# How to intercept incoming sms with my custom sms app?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, sms

I've almost made my sms app, only one bug still remains. When phone receives incoming sms it somehow goes to my app and to default one. I thought that problem was in action of intent, but changing it does nothing. The question is - how to intercept incoming sms and forbid default app to do the same?

**AndroidManifest:**

```
<manifest package="lexzcq.com.smska"
          xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS"/>
    <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.SET_PREFERRED_APPLICATIONS"
        tools:ignore="ProtectedPermissions"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/logo"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter android:priority="999">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.APP_MESSAGING"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <receiver
            android:name=".SmsReceiver"
            android:permission="android.permission.BROADCAST_SMS"
            >
            <intent-filter android:priority="999">
                <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED"/>

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.APP_MESSAGING"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <activity android:name=".ChatWindow">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.lexzcq.com.lexzcq.sms_receive_intent"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <application android:name=".MyApp">
        </application>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

**SmsReceiver.class**

```
public class SmsReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive (Context context, Intent intent) {

*//here I handle sms from pdus*

            Intent broadcastIntent = new Intent ()
                    .putExtra ("address", address)
                    .putExtra ("body", body)
                    .setAction ("com.lexzcq.sms_receive_intent");

*//here I'm writing sms to database*

            context.sendBroadcast (broadcastIntent);

            abortBroadcast ();
        }
    }
}
```

If needed - I can provide broadcast receivers from MainActivity.class
P.S. Most weird part - that when I'm sending sms it somehow saves to default app but I didn't broadcast it with SMS_RECEIVED_ACTION.

Comment: You cannot prevent the default SMS app from receiving messages.

Comment: As for your P.S., that is expected behavior. As of KitKat, if your app is not the default, its outgoing messages are automatically written to the SMS Provider by the system.

Comment: Thanks for explanation, at least now I know that it's not my mistake.

Comment: No problem. Yeah, since KitKat, SMS apps that are not the default app are rather restricted in what they can do. You can pretty much just send and receive messages.